# Update method in observer interface

Tags: java

In java as we know we have to implement  observer interface to create a a dependency relationship.Therefore we implement the update method  inside the class which implements observer interface.It accepts *Observable type object* as its input.I want to know  can I access the  original observable object via that *observable object*?

Comment: What do you mean "original observable"?  You mean the `Observable` prior to it being changed?  I don't think that's how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is what is passed into the update method in the `Observer`.

```
void update(Observable o, Object arg)
```

The parameter `o` is the **observed** object, and the arg object is what is passed in when you call:

```
notifyObservers(Object arg)
```

From the **Observable** object.

Comment: Maybe you should study the observer pattern a bit more http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer